# Save highlighted text in Chrome extension without using database

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been looking at a few of the highlighting extensions available for Chrome and the only way they've been saving highlighted webpages is by feeding the information to a database. Is there a way to save highlights without doing this 1) at least for while that current page is still up OR 2) permanently as a bookmark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Etai is right,
Following is a code example :

```
data = getHighlights();
chrome.storage.local.set({"userData": data});
```

and also add

```
  "permissions":[
    "storage",
  ]
```

to your manifest

Answer (score 0):

Use the chrome.storage API. You can save to local via storage.local:
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage#property-local